# How to get the XPath of a grid cell using Firebug?

Tags: firefox, selenium, xpath, firebug

I am working on a UI. My job is to automate it. I came across the following grid.

[image: This is the grid I am working on.]

When you click on any cell under the *Rule* column, a browse button appears.

[image: After clicking a cell Under Rule column]

I am supposed to automate this scenario. So, using Firebug I am trying to extract the XPath of that cell. 
I used Firebug's inspector to locate that particular cell, so that I can write the XPath for it, but I am unable to locate that cell. Instead, the entire row is getting selected, as shown in next images.

[image: Entire row gets highlighted when the cell is hovered using Firebug's inspector tool]

[image: Found element after selecting that entire highlighted row]

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Can you please share your code that you've tried, so that, we can look where it is going wrong

Answer (score 0):

below code might help you to verify the grid values,

```
 public void verifyTableValues(String expectedValue
                ) {
            try {
            //List of Fields values which you want to verify
                List<String> expectedValues = Arrays.asList(expectedValue.split("#"));
                // you will get the number of rows in Table Select the xpath to /tr
                String tableRow = driver.findElements(By.xpath(//table row constant));
                int tableRwCnt = getCount(tableRow);
                // you will get the number of Columns in Table Select the xpath to /td
                String tableColumn = driver.findElements(By.xpath(//table Column constant));

                int tableColumnCnt = getCount(tableColumn);

                for (int cnt = 1; cnt <= tableRwCnt; cnt++) {
                    for (int listCount = 1; listCount <= tableColumnCnt; listCount++) {
                        String actualVal = findElement(By.xpath(tableColumn + "[" + cnt + "]/td["
                                + expectedValues.get(listCount) + "]").getText();
                        String expectdVal = expectedValues.get(listCount);
                        Assert.assertEquals("Value from table doent Match", expectdVal, actualVal);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
             // code for exception                

            }
        }


Parameter: expectedValue = test1#test2#test4#test4 (Grid values)
```